# $Q⊂L$ is a field extension with $ [L : Q] = 32$. Show that 2 is not a third power in $L$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Suppose that $Q⊂L$ is a field extension with $ [L : Q] =  32$. We have to show that 2 is not a third power in $L$.

My try:Actually I could not understand what is required to show .Please help in understanding this one.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha\in L$ such that $\alpha^3=2$, then $[Q(\alpha):Q]=3$.What can you say about [L:Q] now?

Comment: I think $9$,correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MatheMagic use the tower of fields formula .This will result in $[L:Q]=[L:Q(\alpha)][Q(\alpha):Q]$, so 3 will divide 32, which is impossible.I don't know how you made it to be 9, though.

Comment: sorry.Now i got it.Thank you.